# Apache Ignite [TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=ZookeeperClusterNode

Tags: java, ignite

I am trying to run a example java code to test ignite sql operate,when there is no remote ignite server existed,the code run correctly,but when there is a remote server start ,the client cannot join the cluster and throw a exception.I tryed a lot ,can anybody help? thanks

ignite version :2.8.1

the config file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Enable client mode. -->
<!--        <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>-->

<!--        <property name="communicationSpi">-->
<!--            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">-->
<!--                <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="1000"/>-->
<!--            </bean>-->
<!--        </property>-->

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="zkConnectionString" value="10.11.102.14:2181"/>
                <property name="sessionTimeout" value="30000"/>
                <property name="zkRootPath" value="/apacheIgnite"/>
                <property name="joinTimeout" value="10000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

the java code

```
public class SqlDdlExample {
    /** Dummy cache name. */
    private static final String DUMMY_CACHE_NAME = "dummy_cache";

    /**
     * Executes example.
     *
     * @param args Command line arguments, none required.
     * @throws Exception If example execution failed.
     */
//    @SuppressWarnings({"unused", "ThrowFromFinallyBlock"})
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("config/example-zookeeper.xml")) {
            print("Cache query DDL example started.");

            // Create dummy cache to act as an entry point for SQL queries (new SQL API which do not require this
            // will appear in future versions, JDBC and ODBC drivers do not require it already).
            CacheConfiguration<?, ?> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(DUMMY_CACHE_NAME).setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");

            try (
                IgniteCache<?, ?> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg)
            ) {
                // Create reference City table based on REPLICATED template.
                cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
                    "CREATE TABLE city (id LONG PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR) WITH \"template=replicated\"")).getAll();

                // Create table based on PARTITIONED template with one backup.
                cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
                    "CREATE TABLE person (id LONG, name VARCHAR, city_id LONG, PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id)) " +
                    "WITH \"backups=1, affinity_key=city_id\"")).getAll();

                // Create an index.
                cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("CREATE INDEX on Person (city_id)")).getAll();

                print("Created database objects.");

                SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO city (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)");

                cache.query(qry.setArgs(1L, "Forest Hill")).getAll();
                cache.query(qry.setArgs(2L, "Denver")).getAll();
                cache.query(qry.setArgs(3L, "St. Petersburg")).getAll();

                qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, name, city_id) values (?, ?, ?)");

                cache.query(qry.setArgs(1L, "John Doe", 3L)).getAll();
                cache.query(qry.setArgs(2L, "Jane Roe", 2L)).getAll();
                cache.query(qry.setArgs(3L, "Mary Major", 1L)).getAll();
                cache.query(qry.setArgs(4L, "Richard Miles", 2L)).getAll();

                print("Populated data.");

                List<List<?>> res = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
                    "SELECT p.name, c.name FROM Person p INNER JOIN City c on c.id = p.city_id")).getAll();

                print("Query results:");

                for (Object next : res)
                    System.out.println(">>>    " + next);

                cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("drop table Person")).getAll();
                cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("drop table City")).getAll();

                print("Dropped database objects.");
            }
            finally {
                // Distributed cache can be removed from cluster only by #destroyCache() call.
                ignite.destroyCache(DUMMY_CACHE_NAME);
            }

            print("Cache query DDL example finished.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prints message.
     *
     * @param msg Message to print before all objects are printed.
     */
    private static void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>> " + msg);
    }
}
```

the java error log

```
[17:44:18,325][SEVERE][disco-event-worker-#42][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SEGMENTATION, err=null]]
[17:44:18,331][SEVERE][disco-event-worker-#42][FailureProcessor] Ignite node is in invalid state due to a critical failure.
[17:44:18,333][SEVERE][node-stopper][] Stopping local node on Ignite failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SEGMENTATION, err=null]]
[17:44:18] (wrn) Ignoring stopping Ignite instance that was already stopped or never started: null

[17:44:18,345][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=b3deb3d6-008e-4466-bd85-99b010632a66, addrs=[172.20.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.19.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 10.11.102.14, 127.0.0.1], order=1, loc=false, client=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=HashMap {-2100569601=GridDhtPartitionMap [moving=0, top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], updateSeq=1, size=0], 1672377397=GridDhtPartitionMap [moving=0, top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], updateSeq=1, size=0]}, partCntrs=HashMap {-2100569601=CachePartitionPartialCountersMap {}, 1672377397=CachePartitionPartialCountersMap {}}, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=false, exchangeStartTime=830556597785017, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=8, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27, addrs=[10.42.0.1, 192.168.91.220, 127.0.0.1], order=8, loc=true, client=false], topVer=8, nodeId8=aa04b653, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1594806196122], nodeId=aa04b653, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1594806195395, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
class org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteInterruptedCheckedException: Got interrupted while waiting for future to complete.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:186)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3122)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2918)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendLocalPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2020)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2155)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.distributedExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1620)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:894)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3214)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3063)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[17:44:18,346][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Failed to send local partitions to coordinator [crd=b3deb3d6-008e-4466-bd85-99b010632a66, exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=8, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27, addrs=[10.42.0.1, 192.168.91.220, 127.0.0.1], order=8, loc=true, client=false], topVer=8, nodeId8=aa04b653, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1594806196122], nodeId=aa04b653, evt=NODE_JOINED]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=b3deb3d6-008e-4466-bd85-99b010632a66, addrs=[172.20.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.19.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 10.11.102.14, 127.0.0.1], order=1, loc=false, client=false], topic=TOPIC_CACHE, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=HashMap {-2100569601=GridDhtPartitionMap [moving=0, top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], updateSeq=1, size=0], 1672377397=GridDhtPartitionMap [moving=0, top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], updateSeq=1, size=0]}, partCntrs=HashMap {-2100569601=CachePartitionPartialCountersMap {}, 1672377397=CachePartitionPartialCountersMap {}}, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=false, exchangeStartTime=830556597785017, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=8, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27, addrs=[10.42.0.1, 192.168.91.220, 127.0.0.1], order=8, loc=true, client=false], topVer=8, nodeId8=aa04b653, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1594806196122], nodeId=aa04b653, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1594806195395, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]], policy=2]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2046)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendLocalPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2020)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2155)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.distributedExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1620)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:894)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3214)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3063)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: ZookeeperClusterNode [id=b3deb3d6-008e-4466-bd85-99b010632a66, addrs=[172.20.0.1, 172.18.0.1, 172.19.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 10.11.102.14, 127.0.0.1], order=1, loc=false, client=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2955)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2035)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteInterruptedCheckedException: Got interrupted while waiting for future to complete.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:186)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3122)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2918)
    ... 12 more
[17:44:18] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:01:04.770]
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteInterruptedException: Got interrupted while waiting for future to complete.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$3.apply(IgniteUtils.java:888)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$3.apply(IgniteUtils.java:886)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1062)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:349)
    at org.apache.ignite.examples.sql.SqlDdlExample.main(SqlDdlExample.java:52)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the remote server error log

```
[root@Centos701 apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin]# [17:40:39] Joining node doesn't have encryption data [node=aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27]
[17:40:39] Topology snapshot [ver=8, locNode=b3deb3d6, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=12, offheap=7.7GB, heap=7.4GB]
[17:40:39]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=2, online=2, offline=0]
[17:41:10,444][SEVERE][grid-timeout-worker-#23][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=partition-exchanger, threadName=exchange-worker-#43, blockedFor=20s]
[17:41:10] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1594806049475]]]
[17:41:19,800][SEVERE][ttl-cleanup-worker-#64][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=partition-exchanger, threadName=exchange-worker-#43, blockedFor=30s]
[17:41:19] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1594806049475]]]
[17:41:29,305][SEVERE][ttl-cleanup-worker-#64][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=partition-exchanger, threadName=exchange-worker-#43, blockedFor=39s]
[17:41:29] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1594806049475]]]
[17:41:41,681][SEVERE][grid-timeout-worker-#23][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=partition-exchanger, threadName=exchange-worker-#43, blockedFor=52s]
[17:41:41] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1594806049475]]]
[17:41:41] Topology snapshot [ver=9, locNode=b3deb3d6, servers=1, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=8, offheap=6.3GB, heap=6.9GB]
[17:41:41]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
[17:41:41,699][SEVERE][sys-#97][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27, addrs=[10.42.0.1, 192.168.91.220, 127.0.0.1], order=8, loc=false, client=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_METRICS, topicOrd=29, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=ClusterMetricsUpdateMessage []]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Node failed: aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7507)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3122)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2918)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor.updateMetrics(ClusterProcessor.java:490)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor.access$2200(ClusterProcessor.java:85)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor$MetricsUpdateTimeoutObject.run(ClusterProcessor.java:788)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Node failed: aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.internal.ZookeeperDiscoveryImpl.resolveCommunicationError(ZookeeperDiscoveryImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.resolveCommunicationFailure(ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.resolveCommunicationError(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2473)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter$1.resolveCommunicationFailure(GridManagerAdapter.java:626)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.processSessionCreationError(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3851)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3776)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3458)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3198)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3078)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterTopologyCheckedException: Node failed: aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27
    ... 19 more
[17:41:41,699][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to send message to remote node [node=ZookeeperClusterNode [id=aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27, addrs=[10.42.0.1, 192.168.91.220, 127.0.0.1], order=8, loc=false, client=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_INTERNAL_DIAGNOSTIC, topicOrd=27, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=IgniteDiagnosticMessage [flags=1, futId=2]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Node failed: aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7507)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:191)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3122)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2918)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor.sendDiagnosticMessage(ClusterProcessor.java:626)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor.requestDiagnosticInfo(ClusterProcessor.java:568)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteDiagnosticPrepareContext.send(IgniteDiagnosticPrepareContext.java:131)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.dumpDebugInfo(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2085)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3264)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3063)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Node failed: aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.internal.ZookeeperDiscoveryImpl.resolveCommunicationError(ZookeeperDiscoveryImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.zk.ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.resolveCommunicationFailure(ZookeeperDiscoverySpi.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.resolveCommunicationError(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2473)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter$1.resolveCommunicationFailure(GridManagerAdapter.java:626)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.processSessionCreationError(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3851)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3776)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3458)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3198)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3078)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2918)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor.updateMetrics(ClusterProcessor.java:490)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor.access$2200(ClusterProcessor.java:85)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor$MetricsUpdateTimeoutObject.run(ClusterProcessor.java:788)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterTopologyCheckedException: Node failed: aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27
    ... 19 more
[17:41:41,700][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][diagnostic] Failed to send diagnostic message: class o.a.i.i.cluster.ClusterTopologyCheckedException: Failed to send message, node left: aa04b653-5238-40c2-9bcf-efe6958b8e27
```

Comment: Are you sure you have ports 47500-47510 and 47100-47110 open for communication both ways between all server and client nodes?

Comment: Hi,thanks for answer,can you clarify more details? how to open the specific  ports,I set up  the below config ,it does not work
<property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="1000"/>
                <property name="localAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
                <property name="localPort" value="47100"/>
                <property name="localPortRange" value="100" />
            </bean>
        </property>

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you're trying to utilize [zookeeper](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/zookeeper-discovery) discovery.
It seems that your node was able to join a cluster but it failed during communication. Try opening ports 47100-47110 on the client node host as well as on the server node host. Or it's possible to [reconfigure](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/network-config) ports. Range of ports is required as it's possible to run multiple nodes on a host. A node will claim a first available port.

Comment: thanks for answer,I set up  the below config ,it does not work，this time the error is :Failed to send message to remote node [node=ZookeeperClusterNode ...
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No session found
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="1000"/>
                <property name="localAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
                <property name="localPort" value="47100"/>
                <property name="localPortRange" value="100" />

Comment: it worked for me ,when I change the localAddress to the real ip addr,thanks